# Polymer Iron Ajax - How to access Response from Request after Error Event?

Tags: javascript, ajax, polymer

I use iron-ajax:

```
<iron-ajax
   id="postLoginForm"
   method="POST"
   verbose
   url="../../login"
   content-type="application/json"
   handle-as="json"
   on-response="_handleLoginResponse"
   on-error="_handleErrorResponse"></iron-ajax>
```

The server always responds with an error if the request body is empty:

> Error: The request failed with status code: 422

This triggers my `_handleErrorResponse` method in which I would like to access the actual response, which looks like this:

> {"email":["The email field is required."],"password":["The password field is required."]}

Here is what my `_handleErrorResponse` looks like:

```
_handleErrorResponse: function (event) {
  console.log(event);
  console.log(event.detail);
  console.log(event.detail.error);
  console.log(event.detail.error.message);
  console.log(event.detail.request);
  console.log(event.detail.response);
  console.log(event.detail.request.response);
},
```

And here is what the output looks like:

[image: Developer Tools Output]

So, how do I access the response so that I can output it to the view?

Comment: event.detail.request.xhr.response

Comment: Thank you... If you wish to formulate it to an answer, instead of a comment I can mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you can get the error JSON here:

```
event.detail.request.xhr.response
```

To get a more complete explanation, you can read the accepted answer to a different, but related question here:

[Iron Ajax - How to access Response from on-response function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40850079/iron-ajax-how-to-access-response-from-on-response-function)

Cheers!

Comment: For me it was
`e.detail.xhr.response`

Comment: @pavel that is not for the same situation, and you can understand why, by reading the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40850079/iron-ajax-how-to-access-response-from-on-response-function