# Iron Ajax - How to access Response from on-response function?

Tags: polymer

I have this element:

```
<template>
...
<iron-ajax 
   id="ajax" 
   url="..." 
   handle-as="json" 
   verbose=true 
   last-response={{ajaxResponse}} 
   loading="{{cargando}}"
   on-response="_handleResponse"> 
</iron-ajax>

<div id="resultado"></div>
</template>

<script>
    Polymer({
        ...

        _handleResponse: function(event){
            console.log("_handleResponse... ");
            // this.$.resultado.innerHTML = event.detail.innerHTML;
        }
    });
</script>
```

The response I see in Firebug is:

```
<p>Hello word</p>
```

I want to access the response in `_handleResponse` function in order to set it as `innerHTML` of the `resultado` div, but nothing works.

I have tried:

- `event.detail.innerHTML`
- `event.detail.response`
- `event.detail.xhr.response`
- `event.detail.xhr.responseText`
- `event.detail.request.xhr.response` (This route doesn't exist. How can it be the solution in [Polymer Iron Ajax - How to access Response from Request after Error Event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35220177/polymer-iron-ajax-how-to-access-response-from-request-after-error-event)?)

If I debug and watch e.detail.response value when in on-response function:

[image: e.detail.response is null]

In network tab I can see the response (simple 'hello'):

[image: Response in network tab]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The response data is in fact returned in `event.detail.response` of the [`<iron-ajax>.response`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-ajax#event-response) event. Your `response` field is `null` because you've misconfigured [`<iron-ajax>.handleAs`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-ajax#property-handleAs). When you set it to `json`, the `Accept-Type` header is set to `application/json` and any response would be parsed with [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). If your server ignores `Accept-Type` and sends whatever it wants, `<iron-request>` will attempt to parse the response as JSON and fail, causing a [`null` response body](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-ajax/blob/c6c5c80/iron-request.html#L341) per the [spec](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#response-body). Note that `hello` and `<p>Hello</p>` are not valid JSON strings.

If you want to receive plaintext data, set `<iron-ajax>.handleAs` to `text` (the default is `json`).

[Demo of `<iron-ajax handle-as="text">`](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/worxQb?editors=1010)

[Demo of `<iron-ajax handle-as="json">`](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/bBoWVr?editors=1010)

---

> - `event.detail.request.xhr.response` (This route doesn't exist. How can it be the solution in [Polymer Iron Ajax - How to access Response from Request after Error Event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35220177/polymer-iron-ajax-how-to-access-response-from-request-after-error-event)?)

The [question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35220177/polymer-iron-ajax-how-to-access-response-from-request-after-error-event) asks about the `<iron-ajax>.error` event, which has a different event detail than the `<iron-ajax>.response` event.

When `<iron-ajax>` receives a server response, it [fires the `response` event](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-ajax/blob/6422490/iron-ajax.html#L479) with the corresponding [`<iron-request>`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-ajax?active=iron-request) as the event detail.

If the request fails for any reason, `<iron-ajax>` [fires the `error` event](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-ajax/blob/6422490/iron-ajax.html#L506-L509) with an **object** (containing the `iron-request` via the `request` attribute, and the underlying error via `error`) as the event detail.

Comment: e.detail.response is null for me. I have edited my post and upload some inspect screenshots

Comment: @Jaime The problem is you've configured `<iron-ajax>` to expect JSON, but your service is sending plaintext or HTML. See updated answer.

Comment: Great! That was it. I have changed to 'text' and now it works!
Thanks!